# Help with a theorem of H. Rosenthal

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

A theorem due to Rosenthal is that every bounded sequence in a real or complex Banach space has either a weakly Cauchy subsequence or a subsequence that is equivalent to the standard $\ell_{1}$-basis. See the first page of [this](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/rosenthl/pdf-papers/78.pdf) paper by Rosenthal.

If $(e_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is the standard basis for $\ell_{1}$ (over $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity), then clearly, the above theorem implies that every subsequence is not weakly Cauchy. Take $(e_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ as a subsequence of itself. Then, there is some $\varphi\in[\ell_{1}]^{*}$ and some $\epsilon>0$ such that
\begin{equation} \epsilon\leq|\varphi(e_{i_{j}})-\varphi(e_{i_{k}})| \qquad j\neq k \end{equation}
for some subsequence $(e_{i_{j}})_{j=1}^{\infty}$. On the other hand, it follows that $(\varphi(e_{i_{j}}))_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers since $|\varphi(e_{i_{j}})|\leq\|\varphi\|_{\text{op}}\|e_{i_{j}}\|_{1}=\|\varphi\|_{\text{op}}$ and so, has a convergent (and thus Cauchy) subsequence. Then,
\begin{equation} \epsilon\leq|\varphi(e_{i_{j_{l}}})-\varphi(e_{i_{j_{m}}})| <\epsilon\end{equation}
for $l,m$ large enough and this seems to be a contradiction. I know I have made a mistake somewhere because I seem to be asserting that every bounded sequence should have a weakly Cauchy subsequence and this is only true in spaces that do not contain a copy of $\ell_{1}$.

I cannot seem to figure out where my logic is wrong and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: For $(e_i)$, you won't get your first inequality for all $j\ne k$; only: for every $M>0$, there is some $j<k$ with $ |\phi(e_{i_j})-\phi(e_{i_k})|\ge\epsilon$.

Comment: Whoops! Thank you @David Mitra. However, I don't think this resolves the overall issue. Pick $N_{1}>0$ and find $N_{1}\leq e_{i_{1}}<e_{i_{2}}$ so that $\epsilon\leq|\varphi(e_{i_{1}})-\varphi(e_{i_{2}})|$. Then, pick $N_{2}$ strictly greater than the index $i_{2}}$ and repeat. This gives a sequence $(\varphi(e_{i_{j}}))_{j=1}^{\infty}$ where each pair of terms (starting with the first two) satisies the first inequality, but in particular, the sequence is still bounded in $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: But why should the convergent subsequence "pair up" for the second inequality?

Comment: I see, so the convergent subsequence is actually forced here to be a subsequence where each term comes from a different pair and there terms from different pairs are getting close to each other.